# How to INSERT multiple rows with multiple values, but only for items that have checkboxes ticked next to them

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am coding a discography tool for a music database.

Artists are able to insert tracks, singles, EPs, and albums all into separate tables on the database.

Having tracks be in their own separate table allows the same tracks to be attached to multiple singles, EPs and albums while only requiring there to be one record for that track in the database.

Which means individual track pages can have an automatically generated list of links back to the Singles, EPs and albums that they appear on. Making navigating the database through the website a much smoother experience.

I have come to the point where I am coding a tool to attach any existing tracks in the database for a given artist onto an album page.

I am using another table in the database called 'trackconnections' to create the relational links between the track ids from the track table and the album id from the album table, with an additional column called *albumtracknum* available to be able to output the tracks in the right order when queried on the album page.

The code for the tool is behind a button labelled 'Attach existing track(s) to album'. The code for this tool is as follows:

```
    if (isset($_POST['attachexistingtracktoalbum-submit'])) {
    
require "includes/db_connect.pdo.php";

$artistid = $_POST["artistid"];
$albumid = $_POST["albumid"];

echo '<strong>Select each track you would like to add to this album below and type in the track number you want it to have on the album in the box underneith the name of each selected track.</strong><br><br>';

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM track WHERE artist_id = '$artistid'
order by trackname");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{           
    echo '<form action="includes/attachexistingtracktoalbum.inc.php" method = "post">';
    echo '<div class="checkbox">';
    echo '<label>';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='trackid[]' value='".$row['id']."' />";
        echo '<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>';
    echo ' '.$row['trackname'];
    echo '</label>';
    echo "<br><label for='albumtracknum'>Track number:</label><br>
    <input type='text' name='albumtracknum[]'>
    <input type='hidden' name='albumid[]' value='".$albumid,"'>
    <br><br>";
    echo '</div>';

}
?>
  <input type="hidden" name="albumidforreturn" value="<?php echo $albumid;?>">
  <button type="submit" name="attachexistingtracktoalbum-submit">Attach track(s) to album</button>
  
<?php }
else {
header("Location: /index.php");
 exit();
}?>
```

*(NB: The post data here is not sanitised for the sql query as it has been passed along in a hidden form from the original album page)*

This generates a page with all track names for the current artist available on a list with checkboxes, with each track name being followed by a data entry box to enter the track number for the album being added to.

Submission of the form then hands off to the following include code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['attachexistingtracktoalbum-submit'])) {

require "db_connect.pdo.php";
 
 $albumid = implode(',',$_POST['albumid']);
 $trackid  = implode(',',$_POST['trackid']);
 $albumtracknum  = implode(',',$_POST['albumtracknum']);
 $albumidforreturn = $_POST['albumidforreturn'];

// echo 'albumid: '.$albumid.'<br>';
// echo 'trackid: '.$trackid.'<br>';
// echo 'albumtracknum: '.$albumtracknum.'<br>';
 
  $sql = "INSERT INTO trackconnections (albumid, trackid, albumtracknum) VALUES (?,?,?);";
  $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute([$albumid,$trackid,$albumtracknum]);
    header("Location: ../albumdetail.php?albumid=$albumidforreturn");
    exit();
}
else {
header("Location: ../index.php");
 exit();
}
```

*(NB: The commented out echos are there to test what the output is from the previous form)*

The 2 problems I am having are that my 'Attach existing tracks to album' form submit:

**1. Passes on too much data.**

The generated form should only pass on the track ids, album number, and track numbers that have had their checkboxes ticked. For insertion into the 'trackconnections' table.

Instead it narrows down the ticked checkbox track ids **only** and then creates comma separated values for every **available** track to select, rather than just those actually selected.

Which leads to annoying outputs such as the following when passing on data from form to include:

```
albumid: 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
trackid: 30,14
albumtracknum: ,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Where it should only read as:

```
albumid: 4,4
trackid: 30,14
albumtracknum: 2,3
```

Having too much data get passed through means that the row inserts won't be correct on multiple INSERTS once I do get this working, as they won't align with one another in the correct order.

**2. The include only INSERTS 1 row to the 'trackconnections' table.**

It seems I am misunderstanding how to add multiple rows to the database with my code here.

As having multiple checkboxes ticked on my 'Attach existing tracks to album' form only inserts 1 single row to the database on submission of the form each time.

Consistently the only track that gets added to the 'trackconnections' table is the first track with its checkbox ticked and, because of issue no. 1 above, the *albumtracknum* is always 0 unless I type a number into the first *albumtracknum* box on the available checklist.

I need to make tweaks to this code so that both problem 1 and 2 are addressed together, meaning that ticking the checkboxes & adding track numbers into each box following the track names actually adds multiple rows to the database along with their corresponding album track numbers.

I hope someone can help.

EDIT TO SHOW REFINED AND WORKING CODE:

New code for checkbox and textbox sections -

```
if (isset($_POST['attachexistingtracktoalbum-submit'])) {
    
require "includes/db_connect.pdo.php";

$artistid = $_POST["artistid"];
$albumid = $_POST["albumid"];

echo '<strong>Select each track you would like to add to this album below and type in the track number you want it to have on the album in the box underneith the name of each selected track.</strong><br><br>';

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM track WHERE artist_id = '$artistid'
order by trackname");

echo '<form action="includes/attachexistingtracktoalbum.inc.php" method = "post">';

while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{           
    
    echo '<div class="checkbox">';
    echo '<label>';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='trackid[]' value='".$row['id']."' />";
        echo '<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>';
    echo ' '.$row['trackname'];
    echo '</label>';
    echo "<br><label for='albumtracknumber'>Track number:</label><br>
    <input type='text' name='albumtracknumber_".$row['id']."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='albumid[]' value='".$albumid,"'>
    <br><br>";
    echo '</div>';

}
?>
  <input type="hidden" name="albumidforreturn" value="<?php echo $albumid;?>">
  <button type="submit" name="attachexistingtracktoalbum-submit">Attach track(s) to album</button>
  </form>
  
<?php }
else {
header("Location: /index.php");
 exit();
}
```

New code for the include INSERT processing -

```
    if (isset($_POST['attachexistingtracktoalbum-submit'])) {

    require "db_connect.pdo.php";
     
     $albumid = implode(',',$_POST['albumid']);
     $trackid  = implode(',',$_POST['trackid']);
     $albumidforreturn = $_POST['albumidforreturn'];
     
foreach($_POST['trackid'] as $trackidloop) {
    
$albumtracknum = $_POST["albumtracknumber_{$trackidloop}"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO trackconnections (albumid, trackid, albumtracknum) VALUES (?,?,?);";
      $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute([$albumid,$trackidloop,$albumtracknum]);
}
        header("Location: ../albumdetail.php?albumid=$albumidforreturn");
        exit();
    }
    else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
     exit();
    }
```

Comment: Looking back over this I wonder if I have made a mistake in imploding the array. An array may actually be needed to submit multiple rows... As it stands, I am too tired to look at this any longer tonight. To sleep I go, in hopes of a helpful answer appearing in the morning.

Comment: You are making it way more complicated than it is. Just use foreign keys and then join the tables. Then you won't need to allow edit to the existing entries while adding new ones. Comma separated values in relational databases are recipe for lots of headache down the line generally.

Comment: I'm not using comma separated values, there's no editing of existing entries required in this code. I am inserting new foreign keys in a table named 'trackconnections' to create the joins. Which is why I need a separate row for each new connection.

Comment: The commas above are supposed to be for adding multiple individual rows at once, not for placing all the commas into a single row. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an entire solution but I see some problems:
You are looping through tracks and creating a new form for each one. The first problem is , you are missing the closing form tag. I guess the browser is automatically creating one, when it sees the next form start tag. ?? That's why you only get one single posted checkbox.
I would put all the track checkboxes into a single form. Then the posted trackid[] array will contain all the checked items.

[EDIT after your comment:  The hidden fields albumid[] post the entire array, whereas the trackid[] checkboxes only post the actual checked boxes (HTML spec).

Instead of having albumid[], You could put the trackID and albumID together for the checkbox value, then parse them apart when you handle the post:
`$value = $row['id']. ',' . $row['albumid'];`
`echo "<input type='checkbox' name='trackid[]' value='".$value."' />";`

ALSO, the SQL, "INSERT INTO  (..) .. VALUES (...) "  only inserts one row.
It's easy to do that SQL in a loop for all the checked boxes.
`foreach($_POST['trackid'] as $value) {` 
`// parse the $value...`
`// SQL Insert...`
`}`

EDIT 2: From my own comment:
Like hidden fields, input (text) field arrays also post the entire array (with empty values for blank inputs). (Again, this is not a PHP thing, it's a web browser standard to only post *checked* checkboxes and radio buttons.  But ALL text and hidden INPUTs are posted.) So in your example, you need to code a mechanism to know which textbox goes with each checkbox. Quick and dirty...You could add a row index (0,1,2,3...) as another comma-separated number in your checkbox values, then you'll have the index into the posted textbox array. Alternatively, you could name the textboxes `' .. name="textinput_' . $row['trackid'] . '" ...'` (not an array), then upon post, read them in your foreach loop with
`$val = $_POST["textinput_{$trackid}"];`

Comment: The trackid[] array already does contain all the checked items on submission. That's the only pass through that actually works as intended. It's only the albumid & albumtracknum parts of the form that aren't respecting the checkboxes.

Comment: Good point on form close tag though, sloppy on my part, will update. But it doesn't break the functionality of the form itself.

Comment: Ah, ok.  The "hidden" field array always posts all the elements of the array, whereas checkboxes only post the checked boxes. An HTML "feature".

Comment: I've amended my answer after understanding the issue better :)

Comment: OK, so with the foreach loop I now have multiple tracks and their album id being imported into my trackconnections table. That's all good. However, the actual albumtracknum field is still only paying attention to the first entered value. So if I tick track boxes 1,2 & 3 and enter in track numbers under each one of them it inserts all of them as the number in the input box under checkbox 1. Ignores all other track numbers.

Comment: Like hidden fields, input (text) field arrays also post the entire array (with empty values for blank inputs). So you need to code a mechanism to know which textbox goes with each checkbox. Quick and dirty...You could add a row index (0,1,2,3...) as another comma-separated number in your checkbox values, then you'll have the index into the posted textbox array.

Comment: Please see EDIT 2 in my answer. I've explained the difference in Post behavior between checkboxes vs. text and hidden inputs. , and the behavior of the SQL INSERT statement, and provided mechanisms to resolve the issues.

Comment: Thank you for providing this, I will try it out soon. Life has got in way of code for the moment. Will report back if successful and give you the solution tick if so.

Comment: Named my textbox name='albumtracknumber_".$row['id']."' and coded the include file to have this variable in the foreach loop: $albumtracknum = $_POST["albumtracknumber_{$trackid}"]; 

This has **partially** worked. In that if I tick only ONE of the tickboxes and put in a track number it matches that number up to the correct textbox and inputs the correct track number into the 'trackconnections' table as a new row. However, if I tick MORE THAN ONE tickbox, it throws out the following error:  Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'albumtracknum' cannot be null.

Comment: Note: Coding both sides of this as trackid had it throw up the Integrity constraint violation error, **every** time. When either one tick or multiple ticks on checkboxes. Coding the input side as name='albumtracknumber_".$row['id']."' at least had it work with one ticked checkbox.

Comment: Sorry I was away from SO for a bit. Without seeing all the code, I would suggest some things to try:  Echo the values (  $val = $_POST["albumtracknumber_{$trackid}"];  ) in your foreach loop to the screen and see which textbox is empty. Also. echo your SQL to find syntax errors. Another tool that helps debug is using "view source" in the browser to make sure your html is what you expected (with the correct name=... , etc) .. If you still have trouble, please paste in the complete code and I'll help some more.

Comment: I have updated the OP to show new code for context.

Comment: The empty/null textbox value for albumtracknumber_{$trackid} appears whenever more than once checkbox is ticked on the form. One at a time is fine, and inserts the correct track number on the inserted row as requested, but multiple ticked checkboxes reduces the $albumtracknum variable to just being blank. Which throws up the null error.

Comment: Think I've figured it out! It seems I need to make the $albumtracknum variable in the include file =  $_POST["albumtracknumber_{$trackidloop}"]; instead of $_POST["albumtracknumber_{$trackid}"]; Once I associate it with the current foreach loop pass it works a treat! Thanks for your help there code-wave! Your original answer actually accounted for this, it was simply a misnaming issue on my part for the variable. I have now upvoted your answer and marked as correct.